# Angular Dropdown Excel Post

Tags: angular, file-upload, rxjs, angular-material

I want to create a selection dropdown that when the user select a value it will send to the backend controller. This is my code so far anyone could help

> HTML

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="dropDown1">
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplate">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let items of filter" [value]="items.value">
                {{items.value}}
             </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

> .TS

```
 selectedTemplate(trigger: MatSelectChange){
    this.filter = trigger.value;
    this.TemplateName = trigger.value;
  }




onUpload(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("file",this.file)
    formData.set("TemplateName",this.TemplateName)
    console.log(this.TemplateName);

    this.http.post(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'MyFiles/UploadExcelFile',formData) 
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
      Swal.fire({
        title:'Uploaded Successfully',
        icon: 'success',
        heightAuto: false,
        width: 400
      }).then((result)=>{
        if (result.isConfirmed){
          this.refreshPage();
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your mat-select tag, add `(selectionChange)="onSelectedTemplateChange($event)"`

Then in your component, create a method of

```js
onSelectedTemplateChange(template) {
  console.log({template});
}
```

Once you have that working you should be able to change that method to instead pass to your service.

Comment: i tried to post it with your codes but it says `undifined`

Comment: What says undefined? It logs undefined?